# BIBO stability of 4 matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, linear-control

The following question is from a System Theory test without answers or solutions. It concerns the BIBO stability of the following 4 systems:

$1) \left[ \begin{array}{l|l}
A&B\\
\hline
C & 
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{lll|l}
-2&1&0&2\\
0&-2&0&1\\
0&0&-5&-3\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array} \right] \qquad 2) \left[ \begin{array}{l|l}
A&B\\
\hline
C & 
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{lll|l}
0&-2&0&0\\
2&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1\\
\hline
0 & -2 & 0
\end{array} \right]$

$
3) \left[ \begin{array}{l|l}
A&B\\
\hline
C & 
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{lll|l}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&-2\\
\hline
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right] \qquad 4) \left[ \begin{array}{l|l}
A&B\\
\hline
C & 
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{lll|l}
-2&0&0&1\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&-1&1&0\\
\hline
1 & 0 & 1
\end{array} \right]$

The following list of possible answers is provided:

$
A) \ \text{Only 1}\\
B) \ \text{1 and 2}\\
C) \ \text{1 and 4}\\
D) \ \text{1, 2 and 3}\\
E) \ \text{All of them}\\
$

My approach:

Taking $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{C(sI-A)^{-1}B\}$ yields the following time domain responses. All of which have been verified with Matlab.

$1) \quad e^{-2t}(t+3)\\2) \quad -2 \cos(2t)\\3) \quad t(t-1)\\4) \quad e^{-2t}$

This shows that all repsonses except for 3 must be bounded for a bounded input (the matlab function "impulse" verifies this). But that option is not among the possible choices.

What's going on here? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition you used for BIBO stability is slightly off. Namely [it can be defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability#Continuous-time_necessary_and_sufficient_condition:) as the integral of the absolute value of the impulse response has to be bounded. Using this then it can be shown that system 2 is not BIBO.

Another way of showing that a LTI state space model is BIBO is by looking at whether all modes that are both controllable and observable have an eigenvalue with a negative real part. Seeing whether a mode is both controllable and observable can be done with the [Hautus lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautus_lemma). You only need to check all eigenvalues with a non-negative real part (so do check eigenvalues with a zero real part) and if you know that a mode is uncontrollable you don't have to check observability anymore. The same holds the other way around. After some practice one can spot this quite quickly, since all $A$ matrices are in their real Jordan form.

Comment: Thanks. This saves me a ton of time. Just for clarification: Using the hautus lemma on all eigenvalues with a non-negative real part yields that for system 2 eigenvalue $0$ is not observable and for system 4, $1+i$ is not controllable. So 2 and 4 are not BIBO? You previously mentioned :"if all the unstable modes/eigenvalues of a system are not controllable then those states can not blow up to infinity by themselves, since they start at zero and will remain there". So all the unstable modes should be controllable/observable in order for it to be BIBO?

Comment: @user463102 System 2 is not BIBO because the mode with eigenvalue $\pm2i$ is observable and controllable. System 4 is BIBO because the only mode that is controllable and observable has an eigenvalue $-2$. And you are correct that BIBO stability assumes that all modes start at zero. Therefore unstable modes that are observable but uncontrollable will always remain at zero.

Comment: But as stated in my answer all the unstable modes (eigenvalues with non-negative real part) should be uncontrollable or unobservable in order for it to be BIBO. Or the other way around, the only modes that are both controllable and observable need to be stable (eigenvalue with negative real part).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen can you suggest me a source which explains your last comment? Specifically why do unstable modes be uncontrollable or unobservable in order to have BIBO stability? Also, regarding to your answer, why does uncontrollability imply unobservability if the corresponding eigenvalue have nonnegative real part? thanks.

Comment: @eet The controllability and observability check for BIBO stability is due to the fact that it only considers the inputs and outputs of a system (it is also assumed that the initial conditions are zero). So, only the minimal realization of the system is relevant and that is where controllability and observability come in. Regarding to your question about "uncontrollability implying unobservability", I didn't say that, but if a mode is either uncontrollable or unobservable then that mode already isn't part of the minimal realization and the other condition does not also need to be checked.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen why do we just need to check the controllability and observability for eigenvalues with $Re\{\lambda\} < 0$ to establish BIBO stability? Is this sufficient and necessary condition for the BIBO stability test? This is somewhat counter intuitive for me. What about the other eigenvalues, do we just ignore them?

Comment: @eet one actually needs to check all eigenvalues with Re$(\lambda)\leq0$. Exciting all other modes with eigenvalue with negative real part with a bounded input results in a bounded response of that mode and thus also a bounded output. Why this can be shown by evaluating the convolution with of any bounded signal with any exponential decaying signal. Since modes with eigenvalue with negative real part will only have an exponential decaying contribution to impulse response.